# Tridion content delivery: TCDL not rendered in REL DCP

Tags: cms, tridion

I have created a dynamic component presentation which contains UGC TCDL tags. The DCP is published to the broker database as REL.

I can see in the `COMPONENT_PRESESENTATIONS` table that the tags are present. (`<tcdl:PostRating .../>`, `<tcdl:ContextVariable..../>` and the like.)

In the `COMPONENT_PRES_META_DATA` table, I can see that the DCP in question has a `COMPONENT_OUTPUT_FORMAT` of `REL`.

I have reduced my test case to a page that does simply the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
  var ass = new Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.ComponentPresentationAssembler("tcm:19-448-64");
  Response.Write(ass.GetContent("tcm:19-429", "tcm:19-449-32"));
%>
```

This page renders the content of the DCP exactly as it is to be found in the database, with the `<tcdl:/>` tags still intact.

In the `bin\config\cd_dynamic_conf.xml` file in the web site, is configured a `Configuration/TCDLEngine/Renderer/TagBundle` element, as follows:

```
<TagBundle Resource="ugc_renderer_bundle.xml"/>
```

and `bin\lib\ugc_dynamic.jar` is present

Where else should I be looking for problems with my configuration? Are there any other possible causes for this problem, or approaches I might take?

Comment: FYI: [There is a proposal for a dedicated Tridion site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion) -- If you work with Tridion regularly you may want to visit Area 51 and commit to that site if you haven't already, it's very close to going into Beta.

Comment: Thanks @voretaq7. I've been committed to the proposal from the very beginning. It's very welcome to see you encouraging people to join.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen the [2011 SP1 documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/cd_dynamic_confN100D6) mentions that the `TagBundle` element needs to go under the `Configuration/TCDLEngine/Renderer` element, however the [UGC documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1/task_E2EA227132EF4BE882275EA1A9EFD84C) seems to indicate otherwise:

In the `<TCDLEngine>` section, insert the following element just before the end tag:

```xml
<TagBundle Resource="ugc_renderer_bundle.xml"/>
```

So that's right in the `TCDLEngine` element and not inside a `Renderer` element. I'm not sure why that is and which one of the two might be a documentation defect (or if even both are valid for certain cases), but have you tried the configuration this way?

Comment: Thanks for this interesting input, Bart. If you do that, cd_dynamic_conf.xml doesn't validate any more. It does make a difference to what gets displayed on the page, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: perhaps this is a good one to pick up with Customer Support then, as there obviously is something wrong here somewhere